# Power Crystals for a more primitive time

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, technology

A recent [coment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/222676/how-does-my-bloodless-sword-work#comment683887_222677) on my [Bloodless Sword](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/222676/how-does-my-bloodless-sword-work/222677) question got me thinking: Could you make a "power crystal" out of radioactive particles suspended in crystal formations?

In counless Sci-Fi sieres, like star wars with it's Kyber crystals, or Stargate with it's Zero-Point modules, we see "power crystals", which are crystalline structures that hold immense power. As an alien being of immense power, this is frankly ridiculous. However, I need to get these Earthlings to believe me, so I need to make some power crystals.

This crystal would work by suspending heavily radioactive materials inside a crystal, like an [RTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator). It would then power my smallest contraptions, or at least pretend to.

The real heavy-lifting is done, of course, by my technobabble-handwavium machines, but if some puny mortal was to steal it, I still want it to generate power.

Can I suspend radioactive elements in a crystal about the size of a human forearm, in order to generate power?

If so, what is the best element for the job? Assume I have access to every known element in all known forms.

- The crystal can have structures surrounding it, but I want the core to be a crystal.
- I don't care about efficency, as long as the crystal generates enough power to run 4 LED lightbulbs simultaniously.
- Even though I am a super-hyper being, please use technology that these puny mortals would understand; modern to near-future.

Comment: They already exist, nuclear diamond batteries. I'm sure, if you're willing to be a bit vague, you could increase their energy output by several times(missed the size described, that should do it without handwaving). I can send you some resources if you like. That being said, the diamond parts themselves are radioactive and wrapped in photaic cells, so you would when powering something, you would not see or handle the crystal directly. There are plenty of resources online.

Comment: You're missing the point of handwavium. If you handwave power crystals, DO NOT attempt to explain them. You immediately begin to erode the suspension of disbelief your audience places in you.

Comment: Also, the answers will generally disappoint, because physics hates your glowy crystal magic.

Comment: @Starfish prime If it's glowing, that means that you're dead. You don't want them to glow.

Comment: For "science-based", being radioactive is not enough for a power source. There must be a way to control its power output. Otherwise 10 kW crystal will constantly generate 10 kW of heat.

Comment: @Madman you see my point, then.

Comment: @sphennings I'm not trying to handwave power crystals. My goal is to create small crystals, and don't generate much power, that decieve the humans, while some handwaved power geneartion ACTUALLY does the work. I want the power crystals to have understandable physics so they make sence to the humans.

Comment: So you want fake crystals that when examined will preform as if they are real? Seems like something you as the worldbuilder can handwave pretty easily.

Comment: While doing your obligatory preliminary search you have of course found out about [radioisotope thermolectric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator), such as those used by some space probes, self-powered robots on Mars, and [quite a few Soviet lighthouses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-M) installed in remote locations. Since  radioisotope thermoelectric generator are well-known and well-established technology and at first sight they completely satisfy the requirements, why doesn't the question say why this ordinary tech is not a good fit?

Comment: @AlexP RTGs are nice and all; of course I've linked them in my question. However, they are not crystaline, and this is a requirement here.

Comment: @Firedestroyer: ??? For example, the infamous Soviet [Beta-M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-M) RTGs used cores of [strontium titanate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strontium_titanate), which is absolutely a crystalline solid. (Or maybe sometimes metallic strontium 90, but that's crystalline too. I thought it was always strontium titanate, but Wikipedia also says strontium.) I don't know of any RTG which uses or used a core made of an amorphous material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lithium tantalate!**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_tantalate

[image: lithium tantalate]

https://www.msesupplies.com/products/litao3-lithium-tantalate-crystal-substrates-wafers?variant=31434238525498

Pyroelectric fusion?  Yes!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyroelectric_fusion

> Pyroelectric fusion refers to the technique of using pyroelectric
> crystals to generate high strength electrostatic fields to accelerate
> deuterium ions (tritium might also be used someday) into a metal
> hydride target also containing deuterium (or tritium) with sufficient
> kinetic energy to cause these ions to undergo nuclear fusion. It was
> reported in April 2005 by a team at UCLA. The scientists used a
> pyroelectric crystal heated from −34 to 7 °C (−29 to 45 °F), combined
> with a tungsten needle to produce an electric field of about 25
> gigavolts per meter to ionize and accelerate deuterium nuclei into an
> erbium deuteride target.

"Pyroelectric fusion" has a sweet ring to it.  Nod knowingly as you utter the words.  And lithium tantalate crystals can be had for only $29.95!  Side benefit - it is not actively radioactive as you are toting it around.  But it in theory could generate neutron particle radiation so hopefully meets your request for the OP.

If one of the humans gets hold of this and can't make it work, gently point out that the human is doing it wrong.

Comment: Ah cold fusion revisited.. how would you create electricity from it, given the small size ?

Comment: @Goodies, I assure you, the like, hydrogen lattice fusion is real